# How do I write apps for Windows 8 without running the official Windows 8 Operating System on my computer?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I don't have Windows 8 on my computer. However, I have the Consumer Preview version of Windows 8 installed. Is there any way to create apps for Windows 8 on the Consumer Preview version? Visual Studio for Windows 8 doesn't install as it gives numerous errors.

Answer (score 4):

To use the final release of Visual Studio 2012 to build Windows Store apps, you will need to use the Windows 8 RTM build.

You wouldn't want to use the Windows 8 Consumer Preview to develop Windows Store apps anyway--there have been substantial changes to the platform, frameworks, and tools between the Consumer Preview and the RTM build.

Comment: +1. Although is IS possible to, it does not WORTH to. Definitely.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you cannot develop Windows Store apps without Windows 8 RTM or greater.

If you don't wish to install/partition your hard disk following is a neat idea to get windows 8 installation going without having to partition your drive.

[How to Create Windows 8 VHD for Boot to VHD using simple, easy to follow steps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx)

[Developer downloads for programming Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See, Windows 8 Apps use Windows 8 APIs such as Directories and all .
So to make any any Modern UI app , you need to have Windows 8 Installed with VS 2012